# When creating link via JS, can its href be JS injected?

Tags: javascript

i know to pros this may sound stupid. but i've been worried lately of all the html and js injections possible out there...

so the situation is, i get a URL submitted. using JS i extract the URL from the box and then dynamically create link element and place it right below the box. could such situation be injectable? can someone inject that URL with javascript that can cause damage? or does this process somehow sterialyze the link URL? i am working on my [mp3 converter](https://youtubemp3.today/), and it's kinda essential to display the URL link...

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
somediv.appendChild(link);
```

could this be dangerous, if URL submitted has something like **'>">);-->alert(/GGG/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url is user input and all user input should be validated. If you can make sure that the passed in value is a valid url and nothing else, you can write it to the href attribute.

But you have to think about other restrictions, what is a valid url and what not. You probably do not want to have links to your own site or some malicious URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you are safe from JavaScript injection here. But I guess you are NOT safe!! You need to validate.

The "url" variable is a string variable, so if it has JavaScript it will not be executed and you are safe until now. Also when you assign its value to "link.href", that should not cause any JavaScript to execute. But when someone clicks the link .. it can be executed!!

Try adding this link in a html page, then try clicking it in different browsers!

```
<a href="javascript:{alert('oops !');}">Go to my website</a>
```

It did execute for me on chrome and firefox!